# CKEditor not displaying

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, ckeditor

EDIT - I made a mistake - this issue happens only when running in iis express.

RESOLVED - the editor does not work when running through issexpress

I'm having trouble getting ckeditor to display in my app. After lots of trial and error, I've taken the original sample folder from ckeditor, and put it in my app. The samples that I got from the ckeditor site, which work outside of my app, do not work from inside my app. I am not running the sample in debug or through iis - I'm just opening the static html directly from windows explorer.

Has anyone heard of this sort of issue?

My environment is Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 7 64bit. the issue occurs in FireFox and Chrome.

The folder structure is root/Scripts/ckeditor/samples

Here's some sample html...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
Copyright (c) 2003-2012, CKSource - Frederico Knabben. All rights reserved.
For licensing, see LICENSE.html or http://ckeditor.com/license
-->
<html>
<head>
    <title>Replace Textarea by Code &mdash; CKEditor Sample</title>

    <script src="../ckeditor.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <form action="sample_posteddata.php" method="post">

        <textarea cols="80" id="editor1" name="editor1" rows="10">
            &lt;h1&gt;&lt;img alt=&quot;Saturn V 
        </textarea>
        <script>
            CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
        </script>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should work this way.
Maybe you are referencing the wrong path.

Check if the "../ckeditor.js" is the actual path to CKEditor's js.

Hit F12 in Chrome and in the "Sources" tab check if the javascript file is loaded.

Comment: Yes - I've checked a few different ways, now included your way.

Comment: In Visual Studio, try to drag and drop the ckeditor.js file in the view, this should create a functional reference.

Comment: Thanks. If I right click the file in VS and click run in browser, the editor is not displayed, although the textarea is not displayed either. If I open the same file from windows explorer, then editor works.

Comment: Maybe its all about security settings in your browser not allowing scripts to run.
If you hit F5 in visual studio and in works its ok. When you host your app it will work too.

Comment: Are you using a .cshtml view or just a .html file? In which one the error occurs?

Comment: I've tried both. When testing the the samples provided by ckeditor, I'm useing static .html files.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the editor does not show-up and page will be empty. It happens due to the missing of skin file from plugin. I spent lots of hours fixing it. Plz use firebug in Firefox. Chrome and IE does not show the error. Also you can download moono.. https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/moono

[image]